# Meaning of dot <function name> in the constructor in C++

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm working on LLVM and found an interesting piece of code

```
  case ARM::BMOVPCRX_CALL: {
    EmitToStreamer(*OutStreamer, MCInstBuilder(ARM::MOVr)
      .addReg(ARM::LR)
      .addReg(ARM::PC)
      // Add predicate operands.
      .addImm(ARMCC::AL)
      .addReg(0)
      // Add 's' bit operand (always reg0 for this)
      .addReg(0));

    EmitToStreamer(*OutStreamer, MCInstBuilder(ARM::MOVr)
      .addReg(ARM::PC)
      .addReg(MI->getOperand(0).getReg())
      // Add predicate operands.
      .addImm(ARMCC::AL)
      .addReg(0)
      // Add 's' bit operand (always reg0 for this)
      .addReg(0));
    return;
  }
```

My question is about `.addReg` and `.addImm`. I wouldn't say I'm new to C++ but I have never seen this type of code. What does it mean and what does it do? Why would anyone want to do something like this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: All those functions return an object of some class.

Comment: @KenSlade That's most likely the case, you should post an answer. `MCInstBulider` seems to be a class, details [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/MCInstBuilder_8h_source.html), and glancing over it reveals that the member functions in question return references to `*this`, so indeed it is a method chaining pattern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This pattern of writing software is called ['method chaining' or the 'named parameter idiom'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

For example, you may have a class:

```
class Example {
    int a, b;

public:
    Example &a(int const a) {this->a = a; return *this;}
    Example &b(int const b) {this->b = b; return *this;}
};

int main(void) {
    Example example;
    example.a(5).b(6); //example.a is now 5, example.b is now 6
    return 0;
}
```

For this example, it should be noted that there is nothing stopping you from calling `example.b(6).a(5)` to get an identical result.